# ld can't find a library when using Waf, but it can when not using Waf

Tags: c++, linker-errors, ld, waf

I'm trying to build my project. I have libuv already compiled in `./libuv` as `libuv.a` (so the relative path to the library is `./libuv/libuv.a`).

When I use clang directly, it works:

```
$ clang++ src/**/*.cpp -std=c++11 -L./libuv -luv -I./libuv/include -I./include
```

However, when I build using Waf, I get a linker error indicating that ld can't find libuv:

```
$ CXX=clang++ ./waf configure && ./waf build
...
[2/2] cxxprogram: build/src/uv/loop.cpp.1.o -> build/a.out
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: cannot find -luv
...
Build failed
 -> task in 'a.out' failed (exit status 1): 
    {task 140349441167440: cxxprogram loop.cpp.1.o -> a.out}
['clang++', 'src/uv/loop.cpp.1.o', '-o', '~/sf/build/a.out', '-Wl,-Bstatic', '-Llibuv', '-luv', '-Wl,-Bdynamic']
```

My wscript is fairly simple:

```
def options(opt):
    opt.load('compiler_cxx')

def configure(conf):
    conf.load('compiler_cxx')

def build(bld):
    bld.program(
        source=bld.path.ant_glob('src/**/*.cpp'),
        target='a.out',

        includes=['include', 'libuv/include'],
        stlibpath=['libuv'],
        stlib=['uv'],

        cxxflags=['-std=c++11']
    )
```

Why can't ld find the library when invoked through Waf, while everything works fine when not using Waf (I suspect it has to do with the `-Wl,-Bstatic` flag, but I'm not sure)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying the full path to the library's directory makes it work:

```
stlib=['uv'],
stlibpath=[os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'libuv')],
```

Oh, linkers are such terrible programs.